# How to implement async. completed event for external usage in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net

I have this simple project to grab HTML element inner data. This is a DLL Project.

```
 public class WebGrabber
    {
        public string URL { set; get; }

        public string Element { set; get; }

        public bool FindByID { set; get; }

        private WebBrowser b { set; get; }

        private mshtml.IHTMLDocument2 doc { set; get; }

        public void GetPageElementInnerHTML(string url, string element, bool findById)
        {
            URL = url;
            Element = element;
            FindByID = findById;

            b = new WebBrowser();
            b.Navigate(url);
            b.DocumentCompleted += new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(b_DocumentCompleted);
        }

        void b_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            doc = (IHTMLDocument2)b.Document.DomDocument;

            string result = "<html>";

            IHTMLElement head = (IHTMLElement)((IHTMLElementCollection)doc.all.tags("head")).item(null, 0);

            result += "<head>" + head.innerHTML + "</head>";

            if (null != doc)
            {
                foreach (IHTMLElement element in doc.all)
                {
                    if (element is mshtml.IHTMLDivElement)
                    {
                        dynamic div = element as HTMLDivElement;   

                        if (FindByID)
                        {
                            string id = div.id;

                            if (id == Element)
                            {
                                result += "<body>" + div.IHTMLElement_innerHTML + "</body></html>";

                                break;
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            string className = div.className;

                            if (className == Element)
                            {
                                result += "<body>" + div.IHTMLElement_innerHTML + "</body></html>";

                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            doc.close();      
        }
    }
```

What I need is to implement *access* to **string result** variable.

**So it could be possible to get asynchronously this variable** from other project.

Perhaps I need some GetResult(); method?....

How I can do it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass the eventhandler as an argument then work with the result in the app no in the class library o just pass a callback and invoke after download is complete.

I'm new here so i hope i did understand what you wanted.

Passing the evnthandler

public void GetPageElementInnerHTML(string url, string element, bool findById, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler downloadComplete)

Using a delegate:

public class WebGrabber
        {

```
        public string URL { set; get; }

        public string Element { set; get; }

        public bool FindByID { set; get; }

        private WebBrowser b { set; get; }

        private mshtml.IHTMLDocument2 doc { set; get; }

        public delegate void DownloadCompletedDelegate(string result);

        private DownloadCompletedDelegate _downloadedComplete;

        public void GetPageElementInnerHTML(string url, string element, bool findById, DownloadCompletedDelegate downloadComplete)
        {
            _downloadedComplete = downloadComplete;
            URL = url;
            Element = element;
            FindByID = findById;

            b = new WebBrowser();
            b.Navigate(url);
            b.DocumentCompleted += new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(b_DocumentCompleted);
        }

        void b_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            doc = (IHTMLDocument2)b.Document.DomDocument;

            string result = "<html>";

            IHTMLElement head = (IHTMLElement)((IHTMLElementCollection)doc.all.tags("head")).item(null, 0);

            result += "<head>" + head.innerHTML + "</head>";

            if (null != doc)
            {
                foreach (IHTMLElement element in doc.all)
                {
                    if (element is mshtml.IHTMLDivElement)
                    {
                        dynamic div = element as HTMLDivElement;

                        if (FindByID)
                        {
                            string id = div.id;

                            if (id == Element)
                            {
                                result += "<body>" + div.IHTMLElement_innerHTML + "</body></html>";

                                break;
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            string className = div.className;

                            if (className == Element)
                            {
                                result += "<body>" + div.IHTMLElement_innerHTML + "</body></html>";

                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            doc.close();

            _downloadedComplete.Invoke(result);
        }
    }
```

In the APP

GetPageElementInnerHTML(URL, element, true/false, CompletedCallback);

private void CompletedCallback(string result)
{
    //your code

}

Comment: How I can do it? Could you provide any example, please?

Comment: Also you can share the webbrowser like this.  public ExtendedWebBrowser WebBrowser
    {
      get { return _browser; }  then you get full acces outside the library
    }

Comment: I'll post other two ways, let me open VS and copy paste the code.

Comment: I have to encapsulate this logic within a DLL.

Answer (score 0):

Here is working code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using mshtml;
using System.Collections;

namespace MyCompany.WebpageGrabber
{
    // A delegate type for hooking up change notifications.
    public delegate void ChangedEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e);

    public class WebGrabber : ArrayList
    {
        // An event that clients can use to be notified whenever the
        // elements of the list change.
        public event ChangedEventHandler Changed;

        // Invoke the Changed event; called whenever list changes
        protected virtual void OnChanged(EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Changed != null)
                Changed(this, e);
        }

        // Override some of the methods that can change the list;
        // invoke event after each
        public override int Add(object value)
        {
            int i = base.Add(value);
            OnChanged(EventArgs.Empty);
            return i;
        }

        public override void Clear()
        {
            base.Clear();
            OnChanged(EventArgs.Empty);
        }

        public override object this[int index]
        {
            set
            {
                base[index] = value;
                OnChanged(EventArgs.Empty);
            }
        }

        public string URL { set; get; }

        public string Element { set; get; }

        public bool FindByID { set; get; }

        private WebBrowser b { set; get; }

        private mshtml.IHTMLDocument2 doc { set; get; }

        public void GetPageElementInnerHTML(string url, string element, bool findById)
        {
            URL = url;
            Element = element;
            FindByID = findById;

            b = new WebBrowser();
            b.Navigate(url);
            b.DocumentCompleted += new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(b_DocumentCompleted);
        }

        void b_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            doc = (IHTMLDocument2)b.Document.DomDocument;

            string result = "<html>";

            IHTMLElement head = (IHTMLElement)((IHTMLElementCollection)doc.all.tags("head")).item(null, 0);

            result += "<head>" + head.innerHTML + "</head>";

            if (null != doc)
            {
                foreach (IHTMLElement element in doc.all)
                {
                    if (element is mshtml.IHTMLDivElement)
                    {
                        dynamic div = element as HTMLDivElement;

                        if (FindByID)
                        {
                            string id = div.id;

                            if (id == Element)
                            {
                                result += "<body>" + div.IHTMLElement_innerHTML + "</body></html>";

                                break;
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            string className = div.className;

                            if (className == Element)
                            {
                                result += "<body>" + div.IHTMLElement_innerHTML + "</body></html>";

                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            doc.close();

            this.Add(result);
        }
    }
}
```

and here is code how we call it:

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     WebGrabber g = new WebGrabber();

     g.GetPageElementInnerHTML("http://www.google.com/web/guest/home", "portlet-borderless-container", false);

     g.Changed += new ChangedEventHandler(g_Changed);            
}

void g_Changed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var html = ((WebGrabber)sender)[0];            
}
```